# Where is this `make-magit-section` function defined?

Tags: magit, functions

I'm looking at the magit source code, and there's this `make-magit-section` function that doesn't seem to found anywhere in the project (grep doesn't return any results).

`describe-function` says that it's defined in `magit.el` and that it has a compiler macro `make-magit-section--cmacro`. This macro has no results in grep as well.

Here's the one place it is being used in the magit repo https://github.com/magit/magit/blob/next/magit-section.el#L635

Where could this function be defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is defined using `cl-defstruct` ([here](https://github.com/magit/magit/blob/3026b56182c767e16f57707d440a680b60fc337a/magit-section.el#L108)).

Comment: Oh, so `make-magit-section` is a constructor function that is defined behind the scenes by `(cl-defstruct magit-section ...)`.

Comment: It might help to describe how you found it. (Especially for `cl-defstruct`.)